# monacaで開発する。　android 4以降のaudioタグについて

Tags: monaca

monacaで開発する。　android 4以降のaudioタグについて
アプリを　cross platform にて開発しています。

phongapにて、当初開発していたのですが、
cross platformにて、audioタグにて実機android 4.4にて
試しに開発した所、音がなりました。

そこで、お聞きしたいのですが、
audioタグは、android 4以降サポートしているのでしょうか？

ご回答の程、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: audio タグの参照
function start(){
    document.getElementById("Sound").play();
            }


<audio id="Sound" loop>
<source src="Sound3.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

Comment: 4.4では動作確認できたが、4.0から使えるのかどうか、ということですか？